# How to inline lazy evaluation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to inline lazy evaluation of objects. For example:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self, v):
    self.v = v

a = Foo(5)
b = None

if a and b and a.v == b.v:
  print("hello1")
else:
  print("goodbye1")

if all([a, b, a.v == b.v]):
  print("hello2")
else:
  print("goodbye2")
```

This causes the `all` line to crash with the error:

```
goodbye1
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'v' Line 13 in (Solution.py)
```

if instead I write:

```
def generator():
  yield a
  yield b
  yield a.v == b.v

all(generator())
```

then the program does not crash.  How can I do something like `[yield x for x in [a, b, c]]` and not have `c` evaluated?

Comment: What's wrong with the generator?

Comment: @wim It works, but it's just verbose.  I'm interested to see if inline lazy evaluation is possible in python3.

Comment: According to [this link](https://swizec.com/blog/python-and-lazy-evaluation/swizec/5148), you'd have to wrap them all in lambdas. For example, `all((i() for i in [lambda: a, lambda: b, lambda: a.v == b.v]))`.

Comment: What's wrong with `and`?

Comment: @Daniel, `and` takes an iterator as an argument.  In the example I provided, if there is a statement that will crash, it is evaluated before being passed to `all`.  So all([a.x, b.x, None.x]) will crash.  I would like to prevent that crash.

Comment: I believe what Daniel means is that you already have a less verbose and lazily evaluating one-liner solution with `if a and b and a.v == b.v:`

Comment: PEP-505 (which has been deferred, but not yet rejected) proposes a `None`-aware version of attribute access, which would let you write something like `if a?.v == b?.v:`.

Comment: @chepner: `getattr(a, 'v', None) == getattr(b, 'v', None)` would achieve the same effect, though obviously it's a much more verbose/slow solution (and of course, it would still be eager).

Comment: @ShadowRanger But it has the (slight, I know) advantage of working :) Somehow, I always forget `getattr` lets you specify a default.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do lazy evaluation with `all`, because the parameters must all be generated before the function is called.  In your workaround using a generator, the generator itself is created immediately but the items it returns aren't evaluated until it is called by `all`.

Your second proposed workaround `[yield x for x in [a, b, c]]` doesn't work because all the elements of the list must be created before the list itself can be created.

Comment: You can do lazy evaluation with `all` via a generator (often a generator expression). But the OP's case doesn't really lend itself to doing this in this case, because the test would be different for each element; making it occur lazily would be uglier than just typing the `and` chain (e.g. this would achieve the short-circuit evaluation, but it's totally not worth it `all(op(*args) for op, args in zip((bool, bool, lambda x, y: x.v == y.v), ((a,), (b,), (a, b))))`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I don't think you contradicted anything in my answer.